# I want to run a working website on my local computer, but I don't see anything being displayed

Tags: web-deployment

I want to run a MERN app on my local computer and potentially make changes/play around with it.
Here is the repo:
https://github.com/Prince-Shivaram/online-grocerystore

**What I did:**
I installed all the dependencies using the command `npm install` and started mongoDB. I launched the server with the command `nodemon server.js`.

**The result**
No errors in the console nor in the browser. However, in my browser (localhost:5000), I don't see the website being displayed. Did I miss something? Is some part of the code wrong?

Let me know if my explanation is not clear enough or if more information is needed!

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run npm install in the online-grocerystore folder and again in the front end folder.

Run it using:

```
npm run dev
```

It says this on the github page:

How to run locally?

```
git clone https://github.com/Prince-Shivaram/online-grocerystore
cd online-grocerystore
npm install
cd frontend
npm install
# To run server you must have .env file in root project directory
# see below .env file structure and replace with your values
npm run dev
# project starts
```

.env File Structure

```
NODE_ENV = development
PORT = 5000
MONGO_URI = your mongodb uri
JWT_SECRET = 'xxxxx'
PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID = your paypal client id
```

Comment: I get this error when I do the git command:
git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ git clone https://github.com/Prince-Shivaram/online-grocerystore
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: perhaps I have to install git on my computer?

Comment: run npm install in the online-grocerystore folder and again in the front end folder.

Comment: @Louis-CharlesMarquis and run it using npm run dev.